# How do I find out how full an lvm snapshot really is?

Tags: partitioning, lvm, snapshot

**Background info:**
I have an unstable system and for a long time have not been able to pinpoint the problem. I have now done a clean install and am adding packages one by one leaving ample time in between to notice when the instability will first occur.

To make it easier to revert to a previous state I create a snapshot of the root partition every now and then. The root partition is about 115 GB and the snapshots are typically 10 GB in size.

**My Question:**
To prevent a snapshot from becoming invalid I would like to be able to check how full it is. But when I attempt that using `df -h` or the system monitor, the size and fullness of the source partition is always shown. How do I get to see its real state?

**As an example** I just created a snapshot of 15 GB size. No changes to the root system have been made yet, but checking how full it is `df -h` tells me:

> size 104G
>   used 20G
>   avail 79G
>   use 20%

This is obviously false, but is the state of the root partition itself. I want to know when the snapshot gets close to 15G (its real size) so I can extend it in time. How do I get that info?

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about data usage in a LVM-snaphot with either

```
sudo lvs
```

here I get

```
LV       VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
home     ubuntu owi-aos---  80,00g                                                    
homesnap ubuntu swi-a-s--- 500,00m      home   66,09                                  
root     ubuntu -wi-ao----  20,00g                                                    
swap     ubuntu -wi-ao----   8,50g
```

I also could have restricted the output to just the snapshot

```
sudo lvs /dev/ubuntu/homesnap
```

**or**

```
sudo lvdisplay /dev/ubuntu/homesnap | grep "Allocated to snapshot"
Allocated to snapshot  66.09%
```

Keep in mind that changes may not be reflected immediately (on my system the result did not change for up to 1 minute).